# Android Studio Fragments I can't get data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

When I am using the Fragments in Android Studio, in Fragment file I can't use for example: `TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rate);`

I can use nothing to get values from my input, my class is `public class MainActivity extends Fragment{}`

Comment: Please elaborate...Fragments do not exist without being in an Activity. How is `MainActivity extends Fragment`??

Comment: Please share the code so that others might be able to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

[Activity#findViewById (int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) is a method of `Activity` class, whereas a [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) is **neither** its subclass nor superclass.

**The solution** is to use [View#findViewById (int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) on the inflated View in `onCreateView()`.

```
  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rate);
    return view;
  }
```

---

### Alternative

Additionally as an **alternative** I recommend using [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for binding Views. You just annotate the field with `@BindView` and call `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)` and the library generates boilerplate code instead of you writing it.
*Note: In an Activity use ButterKnife.bind(this).*

Here is a code sample from their site:

```
public class FancyFragment extends Fragment {
  @BindView(R.id.rate) TextView textViewToChange;  //it is automatically cast to TextView
  @BindView(R.id.button) Button button;  //or a button

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);  //do not forget this!
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't overcomplicate the answer with libraries. Please make sure you answer in the way the question has been asked i.e without **ButterKnife** here.

Comment: @NileshSingh I hope the reformatted, rearranged and completed answer is now more to you liking :-)